# Disable Chrome Extension Minification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, minify

I've been working on a Chrome extension and I have a minor annoyance with debugging my scripts. My background page is a Javascript file and it is always minified automatically by Chrome. You can see how this becomes a pain to use the developer tools on because everything is on a single line. Anyone know if this can be disabled?

Comment: Can you provide a sample extension, and mention your Chrome version? To show the issue, a screenshot may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To view your Chrome extension source normally:

1 open Chrome's extension management page
2 make sure developer mode is checked

[image]

3 click link after inspect views to open extension files in chrome developer tools window

[image]

4 click link to included script file in background page to view background script

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is relevant.

http://www.elijahmanor.com/7-chrome-tips-developers-designers-may-not-know/

2. The ability to Pretty Print ( a.k.a. unminify ) JavaScript source

Sometimes I'm trying to figure out a bug and unfortunately the JavaScript that was included has been minified. As you are aware trying to debug a minified file is nearly impossible. How do you set a break point on a line that is a bazillion characters long?

Thankfully Chrome has a Pretty Print feature that will take a minified JavaScript file and format it property. All you need to do is to click the "{ }" icon on the bottom toolbar to activate this feature. Of course the names will still be obfuscated ( depending on what program minfied the JavaScript in the first place ), but you will at least be able to set break points and debug the code.